# ios CellForRowAtIndexPath is called too much, causing a NSRangeException

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've go an array with two data in it :

```
{
    name = "Foo";
    nbLikes = 11;
},
    {
    name = "Bar";
    nbLikes = 5;
}
```

the problem is, when I want to parse theses data with cellForRowAtIndexPath, I got an NSRangeException because they try to look at the index 2 of my array.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

here's the code in CellForRowAtIndePath :

> ```
>     NSString *cellLike = @"cellFanItem";
>     customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellLike];
>     if (cell == nil)
>         cell = [customCell new];
>     cell.primaryLabel.text = [tmpfanname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>     cell.secondaryLabel.text = [tmpNbLike objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>     cell.backgroundColor=RGB(0, 0, 0);
>     return (cell);
> ```

Do someone know why it's called too much ? any explanation about it ?

Comment: Your numberOfRowsInSection method probably returns higher number than you have items in `tmpfanname` and/or `tmpNbLike` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array doesn't have object at index you are accessing.

Set numberofrowsinsection method to return array count.

Answer (score 0):

Check numberOfRowsInSection function. The arrays tmpfanname and tmpNbLike should have same number of items

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

  return [tmpfanname count];

  }